# What's causing the lack of secret_key_base on CircleCI with Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, circleci, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a Rails 5.2 application that it's using Devise. Everything is working fine on my computer but when I try to run the tests in CircleCI I get this error:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
bundle exec rake db:create
rake aborted!
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

  config.secret_key = 'faa1201370967c22ce2136d7ad84e50705ed50395292b9fde9f76b04dae12bb9e25246418393d779cbae15b259bac0e3430d28ff24c166c08ece1cae2ac19531'
```

You can see it here: https://circleci.com/gh/dashmantech/modulator/12

The comment and default setting on `devise.rb` is:

```
  # The secret key used by Devise. Devise uses this key to generate
  # random tokens. Changing this key will render invalid all existing
  # confirmation, reset password and unlock tokens in the database.
  # Devise will use the `secret_key_base` as its `secret_key`
  # by default. You can change it below and use your own secret key.
  # config.secret_key = "53552bdcd8ec0bb6a83d984380ae1a81233f73cce6093441b097efe1b6bd893eec5da67f2fb3afa3b23242e1b1f089c56eb82621996946f8960d8d71f95602cf"
```

It seems Devise would pick up the Rails' secret key base. I have defined `SECRET_KEY_BASE` in my CircleCI settings (on their web UI) and it seems to be properly exported:

[image]

Why am I getting this error? What am I missing? What's the Rails-5.2-way of handling this `secret_key_base` for testing and prod?

The full source code for my application is here: https://github.com/dashmantech/modulator (I'm not sure what's relevant for this issue).

Comment: I don't see `SECRET_KEY_BASE` defined in your `circleci.yml` config. Also there is no any kind of settings related to the `secret_key` in your `devise.rb` file.

Comment: @Зелёный: SECRET_KEY_BASE is in the environment variables of CircleCI, not on `circleci.yml`. I'm adding a screenshot to show it's working, but you can see it yourself in the output from CircleCI. What setting is necessary in `devise.rb`?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dashmantech/modulator/blob/master/config/initializers/devise.rb#L12) you need to set `config.secret_key = ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']`.

Comment: It says: "Devise will use the `secret_key_base` as its `secret_key` by default", which I would assume means that Devise will use Rails' `secret_key_base` as `secret_key` without having to manually set it. I think the code that picks it up is this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/6c916488af936655f896b8631d17ec0563326f73/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb

Comment: @pupeno that works if you have `secrets.yml` with `secret_key_base`, do you?

Comment: @PardeepSaini: I haven't commented it out, that's the default. It's commented out by default.

Comment: @Зелёный: I don't, which is why I'm asking the question. Trying to figure out what's going on secret_key_base in Rails 5.2.

Comment: You need either puts a file `secrets.yml` with `secret_key_base` inside, or set it in `devise.rb`.

Comment: Is the default in Rails 5.2 to have to create `secrets.yml`?

Comment: If I just add it to `devise.rb`, anything else that needs `secret_key_base` wouldn't have it, so, I'd rather not do that.

Comment: I revised the question to show that I'm trying to figure out the proper way of handling secret key base on Rails 5.2.

Comment: You need to have the secret_key_base in your app. The right place to add it is environment/production.rb . And the code is `config.secret_key_base=ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` (or the name you give it in circle ci, maybe lower case or anything else). If it's not added the app doesn't retrieve it from the circle ci environment variables. Your app has no knowledge of the circle ci variables until you fetch them.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same issue (using Rails 5.2.1 and Devise 4.4.3).

I just solved it by **updating** the Devise gem to **4.5.0**.

(I still have no idea why Devise couldn't get the secret_key_base in prod though...)